# encrypt http POST parameter without https

Tags: android, encryption, http-post

I have an app where user log in to a server by sending username and password with POST resuqest, so i need to encrypt that data. Unfortunately my server doesn't support https protocol.
I've already implement some RSA function for encrypt/decrypt body content, but i don't know what to do for POST parameter

Comment: What is your actual requirement? Encrypting the data will for instance not protect you against a man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: Have you done any research, or have any ideas of where to start? It is good to show a little work went in before you asked the question.